# When to use 勿忘我 vs 不忘我 vs 别忘我

Tags: word-choice

Is there any reason why 勿忘我 seems to be used more?

are there specific scenarios or reasons why you would say 不忘我 or 别忘我 instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are 3 major reasons:

1. `勿忘我` is kind of idiom that everyone use it.
2. We barely use `不忘我` and `别忘我` because they have some grammar issues. Instead, `不要忘了我` and `别忘了我` are the right expression.
3. `勿忘我` much better than the other two from perspective of literature.

Comment: So if you were to use it in normal speech, which would you prefer?  if you wanted to say "don't forget me"

Comment: 别 is the norm for "don't".

Comment: May I ask what the grammar issue with 别忘我 is?

Comment: @MattyAyOh You could say "别忘了我" or "不要忘了我" orally, they are almost the same. But don't use "不忘我" or "别忘我", native speakers don't  say it that way.

Comment: @Philipp `别忘我` is lack of the preposition `了`. You may think that `勿忘我` is also lack of the preposition, but `勿忘我` is kind of archaism, in this case the preposition is omitted.

Comment: @WeiboLi Since when is 了 a preposition? I have seen it described as modal (or other) particle 语气词/助词 or aspect marker 体标记, but not as a preposition 介词/前置词.

Comment: @WeiboLi But terminological issues aside, I don’t think there’s anything wrong with 别忘我, apart from it sounding very short. It could be made more pleasing to the ear by adding 了 or 吧, of course, but is not incorrect as it is. Baidu has about 2.5 Million hits for "别忘了我" and about 1.5Million hits for "别忘我".

Comment: @Philipp I don't think Baidu hit count is a powerful proof. There do exist some sentences that contains the three characters  `别忘我`, but they are only some particular scenarios.  As a native speaker I dare say that using `别忘我` to express the meaning of `don't forget me` sounds really weird.